# Control Navigation drawer in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I have split out my toolbar and navigation drawer into separate components and using vuex to control the drawerState

in mobile mode, the hamburger icon opens and closes the  nav drawer fine, but in full expanded Desktop mode it has no effect on the drawer.

in Drawer Component:

```
<v-navigation-drawer dark fixed  v-model="drawerState" app>


     ...mapMutations('global', ['toggleDrawer']), // in methods

     ...mapState('global', ['drawer']), // in computed



drawerState: {
  get() {
    return this.drawer

  },
  set(val) {

     this.toggleDrawer(val)
  }
}
```

In Toolbar Component:

```
 <v-toolbar-side-icon color="white--text" @click.stop="toggleDrawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>

methods: {
...mapMutations('global', ['toggleDrawer']),
```

In vuex module:

```
    const mutations = {
  toggleDrawer(state, val) {
    state.drawer = val

  },
```

Any ideas how to make it work in desktop too

Comment: Kind of confusing trying to piece together your question, not going to lie...but it appears you are missing `getters`?  It's odd this works on mobile but not desktop, which I would think points to a styling issue vs component/store issue... Here is an example that may be able to help: https://codepen.io/JamieCurnow/pen/GYxgYj

Comment: @MattOestreich, Thanks, got it working by following the link you shared. i needed the same computed property in both components (navdrawer + toolbar) in the format there with get/set

Comment: Glad you got it working!